# Salvar objeto com letra maiúscula vs minúscula

Tags: java, mysql, primefaces

Eu acho que tinha postado uma dúvida anteriormente igual a esta, mas não encontrei.

Possuo um entidade Fabricante onde eu quero persistir, para evitar diferenciar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, posso salvar um Objeto com tudo maiúsculo ou minúsculo? Isso é boa pratica?

Comment: Qual o SGBD? MySql, SQL Server, SQLite?

Comment: estou usando o Mysql

Comment: A priori, deixe o banco tomar de conta na hora de fazer comparações. Isso você garante na criação da tabela. Vou tentar descrever melhor numa resposta

Comment: no caso estou usando JPA e Hibernate, não sei se existe alguma anotação ou algo do tipo que possa facilitar.

Answer (score 2):

Estamos aqui lidando com a persistência de objetos vindos do browser. Precisamos garantir que, no banco de dados, não haja diferença entre o nome do Fabricante todo em caixa alta ou todo em caixa baixa.

Assumindo que a informação digitada pelo usuário é a certa a maior parte das vezes, não devemos (na maioria das vezes) meter a mão nos dados e fazer uma coerção neles. Nem mesmo a coerção de forçar caixa alta/baixa.

O ideal é que o SGBD trate essa coluna como insensível ao caso/*case insensitive*. É possível especificar como será a criação da coluna usando a propriedade `columnDefinition` anotação `@Column`. Por exemplo, no SO internacional, fizeram [um exemplo de mudar a *collation* de uma coluna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3161056/4438007) para `latin1_general_cs`.

No caso do MySQL, existem diversos padrões de *collate* e [modos de se colocar numa coluna](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html). Se o valor do *collate* for omitido, ele usará o padrão para a tabela; caso esse também seja omitido, ele usará o que está configurado no banco.

No nosso caso, queremos ter certeza de que será insensível ao caso, então podemos colocar na coluna:

```
// baseado no exemplo do link do SO internacional
@Column(name = "NAME_COL", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(250) COLLATE latin1_general_ci")
private String name;
```

Leitura recomendada:

- [*collate*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html)
- [*collate* no MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html)

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. não entendi bem esse COLLATE latin1_general_ci ? dessa forma ele armazena em caixa alta?

Comment: Por nada. Se lhe foi útil, peço para que dê um upvote ;-]

Comment: Não. O _collate_ não indica armazenamento, mas índica como será tratado o valor em operações. Na resposta, justifico porque quero armazenar do jeito que foi informado pelo usuário.

Comment: @daysonrodrigues Seria bom também encontrar uma forma de deixar o banco como case ***insensitive*** por padrão, de modo a não precisar especificar isso em cada coluna. Deixar o banco case sensitive e forçar um case na hora de gravar (seja maiúsculo ou minúsculo), te obrigará a forçar o case também na hora de pesquisar, dando muito mais trabalho e se não for feito com muito cuidado pode acarretar até problemas de performance.

Comment: Minha resposta foi na coluna, então garanto pesquisa também. Faz tempo que não mexo em MySQL, não lembro como se muda o _collate_ padrão. Entretanto, creio que as referências que eu pus ajudem na pesquisa desse ponto